# override save, save another instance

Tags: django

I have time log entries and when I save an entry, I want to automatically set the previous record's end_time to the start_time of the editted record because there should not be any gaps.

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...

    @property
    def previous_entry(self):
        user_previous_records = LogEntry.objects.filter(driver=self.driver, start_time__lt=self.start_time)
        previous_entry = user_previous_records.latest('start_time')

        return previous_entry

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('checking previous entry, which is id %s' % self.previous_entry.id)
        if self.previous_entry.end_time != self.start_time:
            print('saving endtime of ' + str(self.previous_entry.id) + ' to ' + str(self.start_time))
            self.previous_entry.end_time = self.start_time
            self.previous_entry.save()
            print('endtime of ' + str(self.previous_entry.id) +  ' is now ' + str(self.previous_entry.end_time))
        else:
            print('previous end_time is the same as start_time')

    super(LogEntry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What happens is that the previous entry does not get saved. There are 3 print statements here, and the first 2 print what's expected. The `previous_entry` is correct, and it correctly says that it's going to set the previous entry's end_time to the proper start_time.

However, after the `self.previous_entry.save()` line, the next print statement says that the record did not get update (says something like `the endtime of 4 is now None` instead of the updated datetime object that it says it was saving it to.

Any ideas why this save isn't working? I think it has something to do with nested saves, but I can't find any documention on why that wouldn't work. When I run similar code in shell it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`previous_entry` is a computed property. You cannot set its value like this.
What you should to, is this:

```
previous_entry = LogEntry.objects.get(id=self.previous_entry.id)
self.previous_entry.end_time = self.start_time
self.previous_entry.save()
```